# Display Different texts when counting for mysql union query

Tags: php

I am using below code to get **Count** of **2 columns** - Reattemptdate & Holddate

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, 
COUNT(*) as count, 0 as Held FROM orders 
WHERE DATE(reattemptdate)  = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY employeename, date

UNION

SELECT employeename, DATE(holddate) as date, 
COUNT(*) as count, 1 as Held  FROM orders 
WHERE DATE(holddate)  = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY employeename, date
"; 
$results = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql); 
$numrowsresult =$results[0]['count'];


foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    echo "Reattempt : ".$result['count']."<br>";
}
```

I got result as below , In this first 6 values are from **reattemptdate** column & next 6 are from **holddate** column , how to display text Hold instead Reattempt in last 6 lines in below image :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use logic based on your "Held" column:
Eg:

```
...
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    if ($result['Held']==0){
      $header = "Reattemptdate";
    } else {
      $header = "holddate";
    }
    echo $header.": ".$result['count']."<br>";
}
```

Or add an explicit header to your resultset, something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, 
COUNT(*) as count, 0 as Held, 'reattemptdate' as header FROM orders 
WHERE DATE(reattemptdate)  = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY employeename, date

UNION

SELECT employeename, DATE(holddate) as date, 
COUNT(*) as count, 1 as Held, 'holddate' as header  FROM orders 
WHERE DATE(holddate)  = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY employeename, date
"; 
$results = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql); 
$numrowsresult =$results[0]['count'];

foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    echo $result['header'].": ".$result['count']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i got `Notice: Undefined index: header` in `echo $result['header'].": ".$result['count']."<br>";`

Comment: Does it help if you change the case of the `Header` alias in your sql, to be `header`?

Comment: Yes, its working now.... as here : https://prnt.sc/kt04s0 , how to display `one reattempt & one hold value` in single line , means `reattemptdate : 17, holddate :8` in first line, than others in 2nd, 3rd , 4th lines so on..... because basically i should display values according to employeename.....

Comment: i dont want to display `reattemptdate` & `holddate` text, i want to display only values..... please help for that....

Comment: Hi Vickey, that sounds like you want a JOIN rather than a UNION.  UNION combines rows from multiple queries into a set of rows.  But you want to combine COLUMNS from multiple queries into a row.

Comment: I am trying to fetch results of 2 columns in same table, so may i use JOIN ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179788/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-sepster).