# Query to get the Employees Column values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am tracking all employees Data present in table **orders**....

I need to fetch All Employees [ column name : **employeename**]  Reattempt [ column : **reattemptdate** ] & Hold Values [ column : **holddat**e]

I want to display that information in below format :

**Employee name 1: Reattempt : Reattempt value : Hold : Hold value**

**Employee name 2: Reattempt : Reattempt value : Hold : Hold value**

**example** :

chittaranjan : Reattempet : 20 , hold : 10

Deepak Reattempet : 15 , hold : 5

I tried below query :

```
$sql = "SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, 
COUNT(*) as count, 0 as Held FROM orders 
WHERE DATE(reattemptdate)  = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY employeename, date

UNION

SELECT employeename, DATE(holddate) as date, 
COUNT(*) as count, 1 as Held  FROM orders 
WHERE DATE(holddate)  = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY employeename, date
"; 
$results = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql); 
$numrowsresult =$results[0]['count'];

foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    if ($result['Held']==0){
      $header = " Reattempet ";
    } else {
      $header = " hold ";
    }
    echo $result['employeename']."<br>";
    echo $header.": ".$result['count']."<br>";
}
```

I got output as below :

chittaranjan Reattempet : 20

deepak Reattempet : 15

chittaranjan hold : 10

deepak hold : 5

What changes i need for above query to get desired result....

**Edit - column structure** :

[image]

**Hold** :

[image]

**empl**

[image] :

Comment: can you show the format of the table you are using

Comment: if you have only 0 or 1 for held columns  how you obatin 10 ,, or 5  ?  .. and also which database you are using  ?.. (you have a column in select not aggregated  and not in group by )

Comment: See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056.  And edit your question, add the database you are using in the tags.

Comment: @Krishanu please check https://prnt.sc/kt0fsx  & https://prnt.sc/kt0eug , let meknow if you need more details....

Comment: @scaisEdge 10 & 5 are the total number[count]  of `hold` data of today..... means employee`chittaranjan` selected `10` hold rows today [count] & `deepak` selected `5` rows....

Comment: this is not in your code  .. or at least  i don't see how you count  Held

Comment: @Krishanu updated question with images, please check.....

Comment: @scaisEdge i followed this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270500/display-different-texts-when-counting-for-mysql-union-query/52270576#52270576 , also updated question with images, please check.....

Comment: @Nic3500 updated question with images, please check.....

Comment: @vickeycolors Bro I would suggest using EAV model for this kind of database where there are this many fields.

Comment: @Krishanu Thanks for suggestion, this project is completed, this is last task pending, please help me for this....

Comment: @scaisEdge please let me know if you need any other information.....

Comment: One last thing, The hold value will come at last right?

Comment: thats right..... @Krishanu

Comment: @Krishanu i followed this answer basically : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203476/merge-both-sql-queries-into-one-to-get-the-performance/203512?noredirect=1#comment392301_203512

Comment: @scaisEdge i followed this answer basically : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203476/merge-both-sql-queries-into-one-to-get-the-performance/203512?noredirect=1#comment392301_203512

Comment: @Nic3500 i followed this answer basically : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203476/merge-both-sql-queries-into-one-to-get-the-performance/203512?noredirect=1#comment392301_203512

Comment: @vickeycolors   . i have read you previous comment . but anyway i can't understand you goal  .. and i have not suggestion for try to undestand  better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way to do it is by modifying your code:

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
  if ($result['Held']==0){
    $new_array[$result['employeename']][0] = " Reattempet :" . $result['count'];
  } else {
    $new_array[$result['employeename']][1] = " hold :" . $result['count'];
  }
}
foreach ($new_aray as $name => $val)
{
  echo $name . " : " . $val[0] . " : " . $val[1];
}
```

Comment: But if value is not there, than it display `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`, please help me for this.....

Comment: i tried this  : `if ( ! isset($val[0])) {
   $val[0] = 0;
}` , seems its working, it is correct way right ?

Comment: @vickeycolors yes, I think so. I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks , I am getting one issue : Today's reattempt values and yesterdays reattempt values both giving same value, any idea, why ?

Comment: i am using this code for yesterday : `WHERE DATE(reattemptdate)  = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146828/mysql-selecting-yesterdays-date

Comment: may be its not DATE issue, i am writing same query 2 times, is it because for that ?

Comment: can't imagine how that can happen, could you post your complete code?

Comment: this is related code : https://pastebin.com/bE1JXUvk , full code : https://pastebin.com/vK0fgQxz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179819/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-atmahadli).

Answer (score 0):

Let the database do the job, it's tailored for it

Change your query to this :

```
SELECT CONCAT(employeename,' : Reattempt : ', count_Reattempet, ' : Hold : ', count_Hold) AS concat_header
FROM
(
    SELECT employeename, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN Held = 'Reattempet' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_Reattempet,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Held = 'Hold'       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_Hold
    FROM
    (
        SELECT employeename, DATE(reattemptdate) as date, 'Reattempet' as Held FROM orders WHERE DATE(reattemptdate)  = CURDATE() 
        UNION
        SELECT employeename, DATE(holddate)      as date, 'Hold'       as Held  FROM orders WHERE DATE(holddate)  = CURDATE() 
    ) A
    GROUP BY employeename
) B
```

It will return a column `concat_header` fully formatted  like you want.

```
chittaranjan : Reattempet : 20 : hold : 10
Deepak Reattempet : 15 : hold : 5
```

Then you just have to do this in PHP

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
      echo $result['concat_header']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its displaying as `chittaranjan : Reattempt : 1 : Hold : 1
deepak : Reattempt : 1 : Hold : 1`